# construct string from regular expression and results (inverse for matching)

Tags: javascript, php, python, regex, preg-match

There is any reliable way to construct string from given regex and "matched" results?

i am looking for something like:

```
stringConstruct('/My name is (?P<name>.*)/', {name: John});
```

with result "My name is John". So I need inverse functionality to regexp match.

Answer in any nonexotic language is suitable.

Comment: There is always [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "No" - that is not what regex is for.

but, you could do something like:

```
function stringConstruct($stringTemplate, $regex, $input){

     if(preg_match($regex, $input)){
        return  str_replace($regex, $input, $stringTemplate);    
      } else { 
         return false;
      }
}
```

But, you would have to use it like this, instead:

`echo stringConstruct('My name is /(?P<name>.*)/', '/(?P<name>.*)/', "John");`

Comment: thanks
Long answer is also "No" i think
I need "guess" original input string having regexp and matched results only. I don't know structure of regex.
This is ambiguous procedure. I can only replace top-level named subpaterns with provided data, ignoring a lot of regex parts (unnamed wildcards)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function. I did it once in Java, here's an example. sb is a string to be worked on. replaceMap is a (regexp, replaceStr) map:

```
  public static boolean replaceAll(StringBuffer sb, Map<String,String> replaceMap)
  {
    boolean altered = false;
    Iterator<String> it = replaceMap.keySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
      String toReplace = it.next();
      Matcher mat = Pattern.compile(toReplace).matcher(sb);
      while (mat.find())
      {
        if (!altered)
        {
          altered = true;
        }
        String str = (String) replaceMap.get(toReplace);
        sb.replace(mat.start(), mat.end(), str);
        mat.region(mat.start() + str.length(), sb.length());
      }
    }

    return altered;
  }
```